# Html is not recognizing block, endblock arguments. Django query

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

*I am having trouble in my index.html file. {% extends 'base.html' %} works. But everything b/w
{% block content %}{% endblock content %} doesn't execute. Here are my files.

views.py:-*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

*base.html:-*

```
<!doctype html>
{%load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>To Do App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <nav class=" navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">To Do App</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*index.html:-*

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Add Item</h2>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

All it shows is a navbar of dark color saying To Do App
I also tried adding advanced things like form but it didn't work so then i added this heading saying Add Item. And guess what **it doesn't work**

Comment: show your template dir structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I inspect elements in browser I can see your Heading "Add Item". The only problem was that the whole `<div class="container">...</div>` was hidden behind nav bar. And the reason was CSS. 
Adding something like `margin-top: 56px` to .container may solve the problem.

Comment: ya, you were right. so I added this argument class = "row mt-4" in the first div and it worked flawlessly. Thanks, man you are an absolute legend. Here is final index.html code          ............ <div class = "row mt-10">..................

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) you must use only '***endblock***' tag when you are closing tag.So you must replace `{% endblock content %}` with `{% endblock %}`.